# How to set 2 different material front back to a mesh

Tags: texturing, materials

I have mesh without thickness. I want added logo on the man cap.

[image]

[image]

I tried this nodes.

[image]

Any suggestion or help how it works. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want to use *Solidify Modifier*...

- add second material (Blue) to your object
- and under *Solidify modifier*  properties check *Material* > **Material Offset** set number 1

[image]
[image]
Additionally you can set also material for generated *Rim*.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for simple node with awesome animation

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you're using a *Transparent* node. Plus contrary to what you say your cape has thickness as you've given it a *Solidify* modifier. So you need to either apply or remove the modifier. Your node organization must look like that:

[image]

Comment: But im having transparent image and with the image texture node, alpha i have connected to Fac. How can i connect the backfacing?

Comment: oh ok you mean you have a second logo for the opposite face?

Comment: No i dont want second logo, i want to keep it blank or base color (blue).

Comment: so you're using the alpha as a mask for the S logo?

Comment: i have added the mesh and logo in the question

Comment: ok I've edited, I hope that's what you're looking for?

Comment: i have attach the same node but still front back its showing

Comment: front back its having same logo https://imgur.com/a/bJDQVdv

Comment: because you've given it a Solidify modifier, so the face without logo is in the inside face, your cape has thickness actually   ;)

Comment: now looks perfect. Thanks

Comment: my bad, actually as I say in my edit, you need to either apply or delete the modifier